# Resource to learn about Long / Short Commodities portfolio

Tags: portfolio, commodities, pnl

As title says, I'm looking to learn more about Commodities trading and how to report and monitor a Long short Portfolio.

Can anyone point me to a good book / website where I can improve my knowledge?

thanks in advance